# Is there a way to access the Google Data API from the Google Apps Script environment?

Tags: javascript, google-calendar-api, google-apps, google-data-api, google-apps-script

Google Apps Script is the javascript-based environment for running scripts on Google Documents, amongst other things. You can do things like copy data between spreadsheets and generate emails.

The Script API is a bit simplistic - although you can get the ID of an object, you cannot retrieve an object by ID, so it makes it difficult to track objects between two different Applications (such as Spreadsheet and Calendar).

However there are is a "Google Data API" javascript API that provides google.gdata.* - and I'm trying to work out how to use this from within the Google Apps Script environment.

My core problem is that I want to *update* existing Calendar Events (or create new ones if they don't exist) but tracking them purely by date/time is insufficient - I need to store the ID in the Spreadsheet and then use this to retrieve the Event later, because it may have moved (by other processes, including humans).

I'm not very experienced with Javascript but my understanding is that if I can somehow 'import' something called 'google' then I can call:

```
google.load("gdata", "1");
var service = new google.gdata.calendar.CalendarService(...);
```

But there's nothing called 'google' available as far as I can tell.

I've had no luck searching Google - just lots of unanswered similar questions - so hopefully someone here can tell me it definitely can't be done, so I can stop wondering.

Answer (score 2):

Purely answering the last part of your question...

The `google.load` is [Google's API Loader](http://code.google.com/apis/loader/).  You can load it as per the example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi?key=INSERT-YOUR-KEY"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I won't have the chance to try it any time soon but hopefully it's useful to anyone coming across this question in the future.